# Getting value from a collection object

Tags: php, arrays, object, collections

This may be quite silly to you, but for a learner like me is being a bit of a nightmare :(

I have:

```
$memberObject->picturesCollection
```

And this shows in the console:

```
: object(Collection) = 
  elements: array = 
    0: object(Pic) = 
      fileName: string = %2Ffolder%2F2%2F9A246297-48CB-4A7A-92FB-B5C18D44E756.JPG
      bPicExists: bool = TRUE
  counter: long = 1
  pointer: long = 1
```

I need to get the fileName

How can I do that??

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Could you try `var_dump($memberObject);` and post the result here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
$memberObject->picturesCollection->elements[0]->filename
```

It depends on the visibility of the attributes. If they are private, you need to use getters.